# remove <br> with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup which is just a small portion of the total markup.

```
<div align="center">
  <img src="v/vspfiles/templates/100/images/headings/heading_shoppingcart.gif">
</div>
<br><br>
```

I would like to remove the two `<br>` tags.

Note: there are other `<br>` tags on the page both before this and after this that I do not want to removed.

I thought of using a selector to target the div by the src which contains `heading_shoppingcart.gif` and something like `.after` and then `.remove` the `<br>`.

Unsure of the correct syntax or if there is a better/easier way to do it.

Comment: Do you have control of the page?  Can you put a class or id on them?

Comment: I have no control over that div or parent div/table. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will safely retain any subsequent `<br>` elements since you seemed to allude to the idea that there may be more that should be preserved.

```
$('img[src$=heading_shoppingcart.gif]').parent().nextUntil(':not(br)').remove();
```

Comment: @user - It works great for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/DuPx4/ What version of jQuery are you using? The `.nextUntil()` was added in `jQuery 1.4`. I'd highly recommend that you upgrade if needed and possible.

Comment: You must have made an edit cause your first code did not work but now it works. I think this is a more precise answer even though the others work as well. THX

Comment: @user - Nope, no edit. (At least none beyond the first few seconds after I posted.) Must've been a ghost in the machine. :o) Glad it worked.

Comment: I swear there was a $('div > img[src$=heading_shoppingcart.gif]') selector there a minute ago. Must be going nuts.

Comment: @user - Hmmm... There was originally, but I thought I got rid of that immediately. Maybe I'm remembering wrong. One main error I had was that I somehow had left out `.parent()`. You're probably right. :o)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$("img[src$='heading_shoppingcart.gif']").parent().nextAll('br').remove()
```

- The [`[$=]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) is the 'attribute ends with' selector.
- [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) moves up to the containing element
- [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) gets all following siblings

Comment: Both this and the  one by Alex worked fine but I like the selector in this example just a tad better

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[src~=images/headings/heading_shoppingcart.gif]').parent().nextAll('br').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following would work:

```
var br1 = $("img[src='v/vspfiles/templates/100/images/headings/heading_shoppingcart.gif']").parent("div").next("br");

br1.add(br1.next("br")).remove();
```